# Observer for invoice creation after it is saved

Tags: magento2, event-observer, invoice

I have tried the following events for invoice creation observer:

> sales_order_invoice_save_after
>
> sales_order_invoice_pay
>
> sales_order_invoice_register
>
> sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after
>
> controller_action_postdispatch_sales_order_invoice_save

and in the observer I am calling:

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$invoice_id = $item->getData('entity_id');
```

For all of the above events, the entity_id is received as null. Also the observer is called before there is a new entry in the database.

What is the correct event to get invoice id after it is saved?

Comment: Can I know the location of events.xml?

Comment: scope is kept as global for now

Comment: `sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after` this saved my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if it is not typo. using this event `sales_order_invoice_register`

replace

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$invoice_id = $item->getData('entity_id');
```

with

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$invoice_id = $invoice->getData('entity_id');
```

Comment: any idea?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65968400/3690413